# I lost access to my account.

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Previously, I was getting access to my page by some e-mail, but now I registered a new domain and e-mail. Yesterday I deleted the old mail from my account, but forgot to bind my account to a new e-mail. Then I logged out by clearing cache and now I can't access to my page.

How can I now get access to my page? Could you help me restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [contact support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), select `Merge profiles` or `lost password` and explain your issue in the text box there. The guys who receive these requests can help you.

Comment: Thank you for answer!