# Change email on mobile app

Tags: support, login

Some weeks ago I lost access to the email account I had associated with my Stack Exchange account, but as you can see, I still have access to it from the mobile version.

The problem is, I logged in with Google every time I wanted to access the site, but as my email account got disabled, I can't do it any more.

I looked for a way to update my login information from the app, but I didn't find it. Is there another way to recover my account?

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221704/i-lost-access-to-my-account) should help you. Follow the steps there. I don't believe there's a "Contact Us" on the moblie app, but you should be able to use it just fine from the desktop, maybe even link to this question to help provide information.